# Syntax error when I try to load file .log

Tags: apache-pig

I have the next line:

```
(2013-03-21 14:36:21,686) WARN TP-Processor16 com.lolo.exc - fail load)
(2013-03-21 14:36:21,686) WARN TP-Processor11 com.lolo.exc - fail load)
```

it's a **log4j** log, and I have to use PIG to process it.
I'm not sure what kind of method I have to use.... `textloader` or `pigstorage`, let me know your thugts

Comment: On what schema do you want to load that?

Comment: File content doesn't look like a delimited format that could be processed by `pigstorage` so I'd be inclined to use `textloader`.